# Programmaticaly click a button with it's UserControls

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, button, computer-science

Like you can see here, i got a button with Name, etc. and i got in this button a usercontrol. When i click on the button everything is alright, but when i programmaticaly click this button. The UserControls will not be performed... why?

```
<Button x:Name="btnHome" Style="{DynamicResource PopupButtonStyle}"  MouseEnter="btnHome_MouseEnter" MouseLeave="btnHome_MouseLeave" Click="btnHome_Click">
   <ctls:MenuItem GroupName="MenuItem" IndicatorBrush="{DynamicResource PrimaryBlueColor}" Icon="{DynamicResource home}" IconWidth="16" Text="Home" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
</Button>
```

This is the code for clicking the button, am i wrong here?

```
private void Window_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   btnHome.RaiseEvent(new RoutedEventArgs(ButtonBase.ClickEvent));
}

private void btnHome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
           
}
```

Comment: Can't you just call ```btnHome_Click```. Just a thought

Comment: @Özgür It's wpf... you need the event or what do you mean?
Like this: btnHome.Click += btnHome_Click;
I want if the Window loads up, that the button will be clicked

Comment: What if you do like ```btnHome_Click(this, null)``` or something

Comment: @ÖzgürGüzeldereli Ah i got you. No that won't work either... idk 
Because i also just got there nothing... I thought if i do the Event, it will also do the UserControl... but it doesn't
`private void btnHome_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) {  }`

Comment: Show us btnHome_Click

Comment: @Andy I edited it. It's more like how i can the usercontrol "MenuItem" to the button click?

Comment: Make it public and call `btnHome.btnHome_Click(btnHome, null);`. Better, add another public method that is called by the Click handler and that you can call from anywhere else.